# how to bind and unbind event in subGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and SubGrid when subGridRowExpanded, I want unbind event expand row and icon expand row data when SubGrid  is null. When I dragged a row from other Grid to this SubGrid i want bind event for subGridRowExpanded again add icon expand row to grid. How can i do this?

I unbind event subGridRowExpanded  on when load  gridComplete:

```
function CreateOperationGrid(styleCode, styleSize, styleColorSerial, revNo) {
    Operation_Grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        height: 250,
        width: null,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rowNum: 100000,
        rownumbers: true,
        gridview: false,
        //==========================================
        url: "/OpsLink/GetOpDetail",
        caption: "Operation",
        postData: {
            styleCode: styleCode, size: styleSize, serial: styleColorSerial, revNo: revNo
        },
        //mtype: 'POST',
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "BenchmarkTime",
                index: "BenchmarkTime",
                width: 95,
                label: arrColname.BENCHMARKTIME,
                align: "center",
                search: false,
                sort: false
            },
            { name: "StyleCode", index: "StyleCode", hidden: true },
            { name: "StyleSize", index: "StyleSize", hidden: true },
            { name: "StyleColorSerial", index: "StyleColorSerial", hidden: true },
            { name: "RevNo", index: "RevNo", hidden: true },
            { name: "OpRevNo", index: "OpRevNo", hidden: true },
            { name: "NewPrevNo", index: "NewPrevNo", hidden: true }
        ],
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["OpGroupName"],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupCollapse: true,
            plusicon: "ace-icon fa fa-plus",
            minusicon: "ace-icon fa fa-minus"
        },
        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {
            var row = Operation_Grid.getRowData(rowId);
            var sCode = row.StyleCode;
            var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
            jQuery("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table>");
            jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                url: "/OpsLink/GetProtBomPattern?styleCode=" + sCode,
                datatype: "json",
                page: 1,
                colModel: [
                    { label: arrOpChilName.OpRevNo, name: "OpRevNo", index: "OpRevNo", width: 80 },
                    { label: arrOpChilName.OpSerial, name: "OpSerial", index: "OpSerial", width: 80 },
                    { label: arrOpChilName.OpType, name: "OpType", index: "OpType", width: 80 },
                    { label: arrOpChilName.ConSumUnit, name: "ConSumUnit", index: "ConSumUnit", width: 80 },
                    { label: arrOpChilName.UnitConSumTion, name: "UnitConSumTion", index: "UnitConSumTion", width: 80 },
                    { label: arrOpChilName.PieceQty, name: "PieceQty", index: "PieceQty", width: 80 }

                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                height: "100%",
                rownumbers: true,
                multiselect: true,
                pager: "#jqGridPager" + "_" + subgridId
            });
        },
        subGridOptions: {
            plusicon: "ace-icon fa fa-plus",
            minusicon: "ace-icon fa fa-minus",
            openicon: "ui-icon-carat-1-sw",
            expandOnLoad: false,
            selectOnExpand: false,
            reloadOnExpand: false
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            Operation_Grid.find('tr[role="row"]').addClass("ui-droppable");
            $('td[aria-describedby="Operation_Grid_NewPrevNo"]').each(function () {
                var x = $(this).html();
                if (x === "&nbsp;") {
                    $(this).parent().find('td[aria-describedby="Operation_Grid_subgrid"]').unbind("click").html("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And i want register event again:

```
Operation_Grid.find('tr[id="' + rowDropTo + '"]').find('td[aria-describedby="Operation_Grid_subgrid"]').bind("click").html('<a style="cursor:pointer;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a>');
```

But it not run funtion subGridRowExpanded when i click on Icon. please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after two day research, I has been rebind susses like this.

1. before remove pus it into an array:

currChild[id] = $(this).parent().find('td[aria-describedby="Operation_Grid_subgrid"]').clone(true, true);
                    $(this).parent().find('td[aria-describedby="Operation_Grid_subgrid"]').unbind("click").html("");

2. bin again.

   Operation_Grid.find('tr[id="' + rowDropTo + '"]').find('td[aria-describedby="Operation_Grid_subgrid"]').replaceWith(currChild[rowDropTo]);

Answer (score 0):

In case you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net), please look at our [demo example here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/hierarchy/dynamic_subgrid/index.html)

Edit: Another possible solution for your case is just to show and hide the icon (href tag where the click in bind) rather than to bind unbind events.